# diferencia entre app.run() y manager.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

soy nuevo en python y desarrollo web, en este caso especifico quiero activar el DEBUG, y me enseñaron dos maneras una mas simple que la otra: de flask

```
if __name=="__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

mientras en la otra tengo que abrir: de flask-script

```
Class Config:
 pass
Class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
 debug=True
config={
     'develompent':develompentconfig',
     'default':develompentconfig,
 }
```

esto definirlo en otro file:

```
def create_app(config)
app.config.from_objetc(config)
```

esto importarlo a otro file:

```
from config from config

config_class=config['development']
app=create_app(config_class)

if __name=="__main__":
 manager=Manager(app)
 manager.run()
```

y mi consulta es porque no usar el sencillo y el otro mucho mas complejo existe, tiene alguna ventaja?

Comment: Class Config: pass Class DevelopmentConfig(Config): debug=True config={ 'develompent':develompentconfig', 'default':develompentconfig }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón es sencilla, en la primera solamente activas el `debug`.

En la segunda forma y más compleja no es tanto para activar el `debug` sino para configurar todo el app.

Es decir, en la segunda forma no solo puedes activar/desactivar el debug, sino que además podrás configurar otras propiedades de la app. Para saber que propiedades puedes configurar con el segundo método, ve [aquí](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/)

En resumen, ambas son lo mismo, sin embargo en la segunda, para una aplicación más robusta puedes configurar más que solo el debug.